# Infinite loop in React GET API call and correct way to use Hooks and useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios

i'm new in React and i'm developing an application with standard CRUD operations to a Express.js and MongoDB remote backend.

In a page I need to display values from a GET API call to a remote server, made with Axios. Every object as multiple fields, and the ***company*** field (the value in *Exhibitor* column, for example is something like *5f280eb605c9b25cfeee285c*) corresponds to the ***_id*** Mongo object field value of another object in another collection.

I need to recover in the table raw the value, make another API call and get the **name** field (for example *Company name example string*) from the object with that _id. After that I need to display it in the table fields instead of the _id.

To make it more clear for example the item.company field *5f27e8ee4653de50faeb1784* will be showed as *Company name example string*.

Also I need to do the same with *Status* column (but without GET API call to a remote server), where I need to display an icon depending on **item.active** value, which is boolean.

This needs to be done without any button, but when I open the page automatically.

I've made a standard javascript function to do this but i'm getting an infinite loop, i suppose because React is calling the function every time he renders.

What is the correct way to do this operation?

Here's the errors from the console after the loop

*xhr.js:178 GET http://myserver.com/companies/5f280eb605c9b25cfeee285c net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
import { Tab, Tabs, Col, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { FiTrash, FiCloud, FiPhoneCall, FiUserCheck, FiUserX, FiEye } from 'react-icons/fi'
import axios from 'axios'

const EventProfile = (props) => {

  // SOME CODE HERE //

  //GET STANDS FROM DB

  const [allStands, viewStands] = useState([{}]);

  useEffect(() => {
      const id = props.match.params.id
      const fetchStands = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://myserver.com/stands/${id}`);
      viewStands(response.data);
    }
    fetchStands();
  }, [])


    // RECOVER NAME USING THE COMPANY ID FROM ANOTHER COLLECTION

    const [companyNameGetted, getCompanyName] = useState({})

  const getCompanyFromId = useCallback((props) => {
    const id = props;
    const getCompany = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://myserver.com/companies/${id}`);
      getCompanyName(response.data);
    }
    getCompany([]);
  }, [])

    // DISPLAY ICON DEPENDING ON OBJECT active FIELD


      const handleStandStatus = (status) => {
    if(status === true) {
      return <FiCloud style={{color: "green"}}/>;
    } else {
      return <FiCloud style={{color: "grey"}} description="Offline"/>;
    }
  }
   

   // OTHER CODE HERE //
return (

     //SOME CODE HERE//
    
             <Tab eventKey="stands" title="Stands">
          <div className="py-12 w-full">
            <table className="table table-lg">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Exhibitor</th>
                  <th>Size</th>
                  <th>Color Palette</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {allStands.map((item, index) =>{
                  return(
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td>{handleStandStatus(item.active)}</td>
                      <td><Link to={`/standProfile/${item._id}`}>{item.name}</Link></td>
                      <td>{getCompanyFromId(item.company)}<Link to={`/companyProfile/${item.company}`}><span>{companyNameGetted.name}</span></Link></td>
                      <td>{item.size}</td>
                      <td>{item.colorPalette}</td>
                    </tr>
                  )
                  })}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </Tab>


     // OTHER CODE HERE //

 )
}

export default EventProfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this part is responsible for the infinite loop:

```
<td>{getCompanyFromId(item.company)}<Link to={`/companyProfile/${item.company}`}><span>{companyNameGetted.name}</span></Link></td>
```

because you call a function within the return of your component, which the function then will call the `getCompany` function which will update your `companyNameGetted` state.

The `companyNameGetted` state is referenced on your component return , so calling the `getCompanyFromId` will result in a re-render, that will fetch the company, change the state, re-render, etc, resulting in an infinite loop.

You can fetch the companies within the useEffect after you get all the stands, or you can set a

```
useEffect(() => {get all company from allStands}, [allStands]);
```

so it'll reflect on `allStands` state changes.

Edit: here's an example to further describe what I mean.

```js
const EventProfile = props => {
  // usually you'll want to name the variables as so:
  // a noun/object for the first one (stands)
  // a setter for the second one, since it is a function to set the `stands`
  const [stands, setStands] = useState([]);
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState({});

  // usual useEffect that'll be triggered on component load, only one time
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchStands = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get("stands url here");
      setStands(response.data);
    };
    fetchStands();
  }, []);

  //another useEffect that'll be triggered when there's a change in the dependency array given, i.e. the `stands` variable. so, it'll fetch company names whenever the `stands` state changes.
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCompanies = async () => {
      const newCompanies = {...companies};
      // wait for all company names have been retrieved
      await Promise.all(stands.forEach(s => {
        const id = s.company;
        const response = await axios.get("company url here with " + id);
        newCompanies[id] = response.data;
      }));
      setCompanies(newCompanies);
    };
    fetchCompanies();
  }, [stands]);

  return (
    // ... some components
    {stands.map((item, index) => (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td><Link to={`/some/url/${item.company}`}>{companies[item.company]}</Link></td>
      </tr>
    )}
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you mean fetching the company name in the same useEffect making 2 api call instead of one?

Comment: Sorry but I don't think i've understood your answer, can you please show me using code? I tried several time but with no results.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I've added some example, hopefully it helps and fit right to your need :)

Comment: > Do you mean fetching the company name in the same useEffect making 2 api call instead of one?

can do this as well